# IntelliJ format XML with a space before slash in a self-closing tag

Tags: intellij-idea, formatter, xml-formatting

Is there a way to add a space in self closing tags like `<tag att='foo' />` only before the slash only in self closing tags in IntelliJ code style formatting settings? In Editor | Code Style | XML | Other there is only an option to add a space *After tag name*, but it also adds space to `<component ></component >`, which I don't want. I want `<component></component>` instead, but `<component />` instead of `<component/>`.

Comment: Have you tried to enable "in empty tag" option in "Editor | Code Style | XML | Other" settings?

Comment: @y.bedrov, thx that's what I need!